# Can a number be encrypted, added to other numbers, and then the sum decrypted?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

I imagine there is a class of algorithms for this, but I don't know the name to google for more info.

To describe the desired behavior:

```
0 or 1 + "some seed" -> ciphertext-1
0 or 1 + "different seed" -> ciphertext-2
...
0 or 1 + "yet another seed" -> ciphertext-n
ciphertext-1 + ciphertext-2 + ... + ciphertext-n = ciphersum
ciphersum + private key -> cleartext of sum of original number
```

Comment: Homomorphic encryption? Or do you actually require *this specific* addition behavior?

Comment: If you need a specific algorithm to start your search, try "Pallier"

Comment: It is called  "Paillier" .

Comment: To complement the above comments, the name of the primitive is "additively homomorphic encryption".